# mysql - subquery and returning conditional value within column

Tags: mysql

Assume I have an `event` table that has logs regarding the various events assosicated to a person by name

```
+--------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| name   | eventName               | data(json)         |
+--------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| John   | email send success      | '{"meta": "data"}' |
+--------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| John   | email send failed       | '{"meta": "data1"}'|
+--------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| John   | created acct success    | '{"meta": "data2"}'|
+--------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| Jane   | email send failed       | '{"meta": "data1"}'|
+--------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| Jane   | created acct success    | '{"meta": "data2"}'|
+--------+-------------------------+--------------------+
```

What I want to do is create a query that will return the results of `users` that *DO NOT* have `eventName='email send success'` associated to the `name` column.

#### The Problem

my current solution is an implementation below in javascript

```js
const results = sql.query(`SELECT * FROM event WHERE eventName = 'send email failed'`)
// above returns an array representation of the example table above

for (const r of results) {
  const subQuery = sql.query(`SELECT * FROM event WHERE eventName='send email success' AND name=${r.name}`)
  if (!subQuery.length) {
  // never sent email, resend email
  }
  // email was sent do nothing
}
```

As you can see from the code above, I am getting all that data and then doing *another* query on each each record to see if `eventName` = `email send successful` to see if an email has been sent or not.

### What I Want

A query that looks like:

```sql
SELECT
  *,
  if(t1.name='email send success', '', t1.name) as name,
  if(t1.name='email send success', '', t1.data) as data
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE eventName='email send failed'
  ) as t1
JOIN users as t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
```

The above code doesn't work, so this is my thought. I create a subquery that will get all the data where the `eventName='email send failed'` return it to the outer query which will then show the data where the user does *not* have the `eventName` 'email send success' associated to it.

What I would like to receive from the query is:

```
+--------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
| name   | eventName               | timestamp  | data(json)         |
+--------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Jane   | send email failed       | (UTC DATE) | '{"meta": "data1"}'|
+--------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8z4Txb3B71xCjfqoaVyYXh/7)

The reason why I want `Jane` to be return (if you look at the fiddle) is because Jane's `eventName` column does not have the vale `send email success` so as a result we need to send another email to her. However, `John` does so we don't need to send another one

Comment: *a basic query like .. returns* Query text and output does not match.

Comment: Provide sample data (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, excess columns may be skipped) and desired result for this data. Specify precise MySQL version also.

Comment: alright, gimme a minute while I add a db fiddle

Comment: added a fiddle @Akina

Comment: Now explain in words what do you need.

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to know all of the people who weren't able to send out a successful email,  If so use a minus union where you SELECT name MINUS SELECT name where eventName is success.  This will leave the name of people who only had failures.

Comment: *seeing if an email has been sent to a person or not* - but what is a criteria? only rows with `'email send failed'` event? Why not simply ```SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE eventName='email send failed';```? [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c1a95d7b08a5960ea01db1c7cebffb6)

Comment: because this is an eventlog and the issue isn't sending an email it's something else, but, I boiled it down to something that represents the issue's essence to provide a minimal report. As such, with keeping the same vein, there could be multiple attempts and multiple fails on different dates, before it is finally sent correctly.

Comment: ultimately it would be nice if I could put, in the `WHERE` clause: `WHERE eventName = 'email send failed' AND eventName != 'email send successful` which doesn't work